# Performing keyboard strokes "Ctrl + A" "Ctrl + C" and "Ctrl + V" on text field with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

How to simply want to input a value in a text box , select the complete text from the text box using "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>" , then copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>" and then Paste it in the same box with "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>"  using Selenium + C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "search-criteria")]
public IWebElement txtProductSearch1 = null

public void copypaste(string strCopy)
{ 
    txtProductSearch1.Click();
    txtProductSearch1.Clear();
    txtProductSearch1.SendKeys(strCopy);
    txtProductSearch1.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a"); //a in smaller case
    txtProductSearch1.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "c"); // c in smaller case
    txtProductSearch1.Clear();
    txtProductSearch1.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v"); // v in smaller case
    btnProductSearch1.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way worked for me is using `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`

Here is an example doing Ctrl+A and Delete

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(...);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
.KeyDown("A")
.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control)
.KeyUp("A")
.Perform();

action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Delete)
.Perform();
```