# Unable to inspect element by text value

Tags: c#, selenium, appium-android

In the attached screenshot I want to read the value of title which is 'Title_6jOa'
But I'm unable to locate the element because text value is not present in highlighted area.

Any solution please.?
[image]

Comment: By any chance can we see the site?

Comment: @kumar, I have assumed you have tried with getText() method.Please check the below answer for the details

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yong , @Subburaj Sorry tried yours way too, but getting no value.

Getting the value in below way perfectly.

**Steps:**

1. Double click in the text field. To get text selected.
   [image]
2. Then copy the text to clipboard using Keyboard key ctrl+c
   [Copy the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906197/performing-keyboard-strokes-ctrl-a-ctrl-c-and-ctrl-v-on-text-field-w)
3. And Then the final step is reading the text from clipboard by below line of code in **c#**.

string clipboardExpectedText = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to locate the field by the class of the field, a CSS selector could be `.x-frs-id-ivnt_Title`

Then for reading the text that is typed into the field,
`findElement(By.cssSelector(".x-frs-id-ivnt_Title")).getAttribute("value")`

If the css selector `.x-frs-id-ivnt_Title` can't find the expected text box, try below xpath:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(., 'Title')]]/td/input")).getAttribute("value")
```

Please check the CSS selector and xpath manually in browser DevTool before change code.

Comment: I already tried that one but it is returning no value. Because in the highlighted area value it self is not present it is showing  ==$0

Comment: Please add the exact code you are using and the exception you get when you execute it in the description of your question.

Comment: Try the css locator `.x-frs-id-ivnt_Title` in browser' DevTool manually, to see the first matched element is the text box you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Input Field Text values will not be be persisted in the Input Tag in Dev Tool.So,we cannot not use **getText()** Method and it can be extracted using the **getAttribute()** method as below or JavaScriptExecutor can be used ([Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value of a HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input))

**Steps:**

1. Identity the text field Web Element using any one of the unique locator
2. Use the getAttribute Method to get the value

**Code :**

```
WebElement titleInputElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'x-frs-id-ivnt_Title')]"));
String value=titleInputElement.getAttribute("value");
```